# Is it a good idea to Use Identity 2.0 or higher in big projects

Tags: asp.net-identity

is it a good idea to use Identity 2.2 or higher in big projects? I asked this question because the versions are not stable, they now reached 3.x.x which is a beta release. So it got me concerned. Does anyone suggest that i have to keep using Membership 'till Microsoft Identity version got stable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 3.x is is for ASP.Net 5 (aka vNext) which is not released yet.

Version 2.x is for current latest MVC 5 and has been stable for quite some time now. If you need to update to Identity, then update. If you are happy with Membership, be it that way. I've updated a few production projects from Membership to Identity and would never go back.